# Create a question-sorting forum for questions that have been closed

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that many questions across the Stack Exchange Network are closed as off-topic, and many questions may (perhaps) remain closed for months (or even years) before being moved to the correct Stack Exchange site. Would it be possible to create a dedicated question sorting forum for questions that have been deemed off-topic on each particular Stack Exchange site (so that they won't remain neglected for a long time before being moved to the correct site)?

Comment: Which subject matter experts would such a site attract?

Comment: @RobertHarvey `/review` experts? :P

Answer (score 2):

Between the closed questions that are not migrated, there are:

- Subjective/not constructive questions that would still be subjective/constructive for any Stack Exchange site where they are migrated
- Old off-topic questions that were asked before a Stack Exchange site for that topic was created
- Questions that have been flagged for being migrated, for which the moderators of the site where the question was posted asked to the moderators of the receiving site if they wanted the question, and for which the answer has been "no"
- Copied-and-pasted questions asked from the OP in two different sites, where the question is on-topic on both the sites

Those questions should not be migrated. In the last case I considered, they could be migrated to be merged with the other existing question, if both the questions had answers, but that is up to the moderators.

I don't see what the purpose a list of all the closed questions would be. If I know that questions are being asked in a site, instead of another one where the question would be "more on topic," or where the question has more chances to get an answer, then I check the questions on that site (possibly the ones with specific tags), not all the closed questions asked in all the Stack Exchange sites.
How many users would consult that list of closed questions? Why would a user that doesn't participate on a site knows better than the users who participate in that site which site better suits for a closed question?

If you are suggesting to migrate the closed question to an intermediate site, that is not a feature that I would not slike to see implemented. The question would be moved from a site where it would be noticed from users who participate there, in a site where users would participate just to be able to suggest a migration. This would not give to the closed questions more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. You can cast a moderator flag recommending a migration target.
2. You can post a question here on Meta, tag it [site-rec], and include a link to the question.

That really ought to be enough, since the number of questions that are eligible for migration (i.e. they are constructive, real questions) is actually quite small.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read here on Meta, migration is a sensitive issue. Moderators on the target site will get very upset if a low-quality question is migrated to their site. The number one rule on this topic seems to be ***do not migrate crap***. That's also why it takes four close as off-topic votes pointing to the same site for an automatic migration.

You say "many questions remain closed for months (or even years) before being moved to the correct Stack Exchange site". Do you have any data to support that? Anyway, if that's really an issue, perhaps a new review task where users could "recommend migration" could help. Questions with the most "recommend migration" votes could be displayed on the top of a list for moderators, who would then take action if they agree.

Comment: The problem with recommending migration is that topic experts aren't necessarily experts on other site topics. For instance, I can tell you what's on topic on Stack Overflow or Project Management or Workplace SE, but I generally have to ask to determine if a question is on topic on another site.  Besides, most of the time I find that if the person didn't bother to read the FAQ to determine if the question is on-topic, they probably skipped the part about constructiveness or showing what they've tried also. In short, the majority of closed questions aren't worth the time.

Comment: With one notable exception... if they can be edited to be cleaned up, migration *might* be okay...